# ASP.NET + SQL Server user management - best practices?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm wondering how to approach the topic of user organizations in ASP.NET WebForms application and SQL Server 2008.

- Create SQL Servers in-built Logins / Users

or

- Create a Username / User and use it to connect to the database. A user data held in the table with password (salt).

Is the second option is a good option? If true please support me with your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Forms Authentication can help you immensely:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Answer (score 1):

For an ASP.NET application, you should be going with your second option.

You **definitely** want a strong hashing algorithm equipped with a fairly long salt to make sure your passwords are secure.

In terms of an algorithm, you should look at something like [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), it's got a pretty good reputation on [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the second option, I dont like builtin logon system. In an old project of mine, there is remember me system and it doesnt work now, and I cannot figure it out why it doesnt work.

It is always better to do your own logon system.